# How to update $window variable in one controller if it is changed in another controller

Tags: angularjs

In one file I have:

```
myModule.factory("SessionStatus", function($window) {
  if($window.sessionStorage.signedIn) {
    return "signedIn";
  } else {
    return "notSignedIn";
  }
});

myModule.controller('headerNavigationController',function($scope, SessionStatus) {
  $scope.session = {};
  $scope.session.user = SessionStatus;
});
```

In another, I have:

```
myModule.controller("loginController", function($scope, $window) {
  $scope.login = function() {
    $window.sessionStorage.signedIn = true;
  }
}
```

I want to update the `headerNavigationController`'s `session.user` whenever `login()` is called, however, I can not get it to update. I tried putting in a factory in the same file as the `headerNavigationController` because I thought that this would automatically update the `$session.user` variable everytime `$window.sessionStorage.signedIn` is changed.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for getting/setting a session value is:

Getting:

```
window.sessionStorage.getItem(key);
```

Setting:

```
window.sessionStorage.setItem(key, value);
```

Checkout this [blog post](http://www.undefinednull.com/2014/02/25/angularjs-real-time-model-persistence-using-local-storage/) for more info about local/session storage.